# R dplyr left join multiple tables without two separate columns with suffix

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Suppose I have a main table x

```
x <- tibble(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), score = c(100,200,300,100,200))
x
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     id score
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   100
2     2   200
3     3   300
4     4   100
5     5   200
```

and two other tables

```
y = tibble(id = c(1,2), score_new=c(200,300))
y
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     id score_new
  <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1       200
2     2       300

z = tibble(id = c(3,4), score_new = c(300,400))
z
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     id score_new
  <dbl>     <dbl>
1     3       300
2     4       400
```

If I join them together it will be like this:

```
x %>% left_join(y, by =c("id" = "id")) %>% left_join(z, by =c("id" = "id"))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
     id score score_new.x score_new.y
  <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1   100         200          NA
2     2   200         300          NA
3     3   300          NA         300
4     4   100          NA         400
5     5   200          NA          NA
```

But I need *score_new* to be only one column. How do I do that? Sorry if there are already other similar questions but I really couldn't find them.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by appending y and z and then joining them.

```
# Loading required libraries
library(dplyr)

# Create sample df
x <- tibble(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), score = c(100,200,300,100,200))
y = tibble(id = c(1,2), score_new=c(200,300))
z = tibble(id = c(3,4), score_new = c(300,400))

x %>%
  # union y and z and join on x to get new scores
  left_join(union_all(y,z), by = "id")
```

Similarly you can use bind_rows instead of union_all both gives same results in this scenario.

```
x %>%
  # union y and z and join on x to get new scores
  left_join(bind_rows(y,z), by = "id")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party. But I would opt for this `tidyverse`-solution,

```
bind_rows(
        y,z
) %>% left_join(x = x)
```

Which gives the following `output`,

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
     id score score_new
  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1   100       200
2     2   200       300
3     3   300       300
4     4   100       400
5     5   200        NA
```

**Note:** `left_join()` has `x` and `y` arugments, and here Ive specified that `x = x`, where the rhs is your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
mutate(score_new.x = if_else(is.na(score_new.x),score_new.y,score_new.x)) %>%
select(-score_new.y)
```